# how to add usercontrol in Updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, user-controls

I'm trying to load UserControls in my Ajax but I'm not sure how to do it. I have 3 buttons in my page with an Ajax update panel and 3 UserControls. Every time user clicks on button1 I want to load UserControl1, and when user clicks on button2, I want to load UserControl2, and so on. Can anyone tell me how I can do that?

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li><a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnAddVideo" runat="server" Text="Add Tutorial" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnAddVideo_Click" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnEditVideo" runat="server" Text="Edit Video Details" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnEditVideo_Click" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnSearchVideo" runat="server" Text="Search Video" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnSearchVideo_Click" /></a></li>
</ul>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate></ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddVideo" EventName="btnAddVideo_Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEditVideo" EventName="btnEditVideo_Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="BtnSearchVideo" EventName="btnSearchVideo_Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do Below Mention Thing for Different Controls with Different UpdatePanel

```
<ul>
<li >
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnAddVideo" runat="server" Text="Add Tutorial" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnAddVideo_Click" /></a>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddVideo" EventName="Click" />
         </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
<li>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnEditVideo" runat="server" Text="Edit Video Details" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnEditVideo_Click" /></a>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEditVideo" EventName="Click" />
         </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
<li>
      <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
         <ContentTemplate>
             <a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnSearchVideo" runat="server" Text="Search Video" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnSearchVideo_Click" /></a>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
             <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearchVideo" EventName="Click" />
         </Triggers>
      </asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i want them in 1 panel actually

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
<li>
         <a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnAddVideo" runat="server" Text="Add Tutorial" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnAddVideo_Click" /></a>
</li>
<li>
         <a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnEditVideo" runat="server" Text="Edit Video Details" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnEditVideo_Click" /></a>
</li>
<li>
         <a class="#123"><asp:Button ID="btnSearchVideo" runat="server" Text="Search Video" CssClass="VideoRoomMenu" OnClick="btnSearchVideo_Click" /></a>
</li>

     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddVideo" EventName="Click" />
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEditVideo" EventName="Click" />
         <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSearchVideo" EventName="Click" />
     </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</ul>
```